# How to clear the filter of a QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: qt4

Instead of doing something like this: (proxyModel is a QSortFilterProxyModel)

`proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(".*");`

Is there a right way to clear the filter? Because that looked wrong to me.

Comment: In qt5.15 you can use invalidate() function of QSortFilterProxyModel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [`filterRegExp`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterRegExp-prop) property docs:

> If no `QRegExp` or an empty string is set, everything in the source model will be accepted.

So the "proper" way of clearing the filter is to pass an empty string rather than a match-all regex.